# Redshift serializable violation error on SELECT only

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift, isolation-level

I am getting a "Serializable isolation violation on table" error from Redshift, with "transactions forming the cycle are: tx1, tx2, tx3".

After running `select * from stl_query where xid in (tx1, tx2, tx3)` I found that the transaction that actually aborted had only a single `SELECT` statement.

How can a transaction be in conflict if it does not insert/update/delete any rows?  The impression I got from [Redshift documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-serializable-isolation/) is that this happens when you have circular dependencies between concurrent transactions: tx1 reads T1 and updates T2, while tx2 reads T2 and updates T1.

But when one transaction only has a `SELECT`, why wouldn't the result be equivalent as if it were serialized to run before any uncommitted transactions?

In my case, I have tx1 updating T1, tx2 reading T1 and updating T2, and tx3 reading both T1/T2.  tx3 is the one that fails.  tx1 and tx2 overlap, and tx2 and tx3 overlap, so I don't understand why tx3 fails instead of producing the same result as if serialized after tx1 and before tx2.

Although this question is specific to Redshift, I suppose you could encounter a similar issue on other DBs with serializable isolation.

Comment: Could be a support ticket for AWS, they can look into details of what was running and why this is happening. From my experience they are pretty responsive and explain what is going on in detail.

Comment: Yes, I also have a case open

Comment: Hi @wrschneider, have find the solution? I'm currently facing the exactly same problem.